# Missing openjdk-8-jre-headles http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main

Tags: java, debian-jessie

we used package openjdk-8-jre-headless. Last successful installation was 14.3.2019.
Today 22.3.2019 Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jre-headless.

Was the package from debian/jessie-backports removed? renamed?

Thanks,

UPDATE:
Thanks, It WAS working after adding archive.debian.org

BUT TODAY (26.3.2019): Location of packageS were moved AGAIN! That is TOTAL crazy.

```
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
[91mW: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Please, do you have new idea, how to fix?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems all the backports moved to the archive(https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/03/msg00006.html)

I managed to fix it like this(dockerfile syntax):

```
sed -i -s '/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until false;" >/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-nocheckvalid
echo 'Package: *\nPin: origin "archive.debian.org"\nPin-Priority: 500' >/etc/apt/preferences.d/10-archive-pin
```

**UPD 2019.03.28**: jessie-updates gone too, updated the snippet above

**BEWARE OF SECURITY RISKS: packages from archive.debian.org do not receive any security updates**

Comment: Great, it WAS working until today. It doesnt work now :-(

Comment: FYI, I'm installing it manually like: wget -O /tmp/jdk-8u212-ojdkbuild-linux-x64.zip https://github.com/ojdkbuild/contrib_jdk8u-ci/releases/download/jdk8u212-b04/jdk-8u212-ojdkbuild-linux-x64.zip && \
    unzip -d /usr/lib/jvm/ /tmp/jdk-8u212-ojdkbuild-linux-x64.zip && \
    rm /tmp/jdk-8u212-ojdkbuild-linux-x64.zip

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is a bad update from jessie-backports, *nothing* exists in jessie backports right now. Compare https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/allpackages to https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/allpackages

Update: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/03/msg00006.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter (still trying to figure out what it means though)

Comment: Thanks, but https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/allpackages is empty. Is it correct?

Comment: So, how can we install the openjdk-8-jre-headless now?

Answer (score 0):

This dockerfile snippet works for me -

```
RUN echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -y -q install --no-install-recommends -t stretch-backports openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
 apt-get clean
 rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 apt-get clean
 apt-get update 
 apt-get upgrade
```