# "Failing to fetch 404" error when running apt-get update in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, apt-get, apt, debian-jessie

I have been trying to upgrade from Java 1.7 to 1.8 using instructions that previously worked for my Debian Jessie build.

This is what I am doing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless 
sudo update-alternatives --config java // select the jdk8 version
```

With simply `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following batch of errors:

```
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 99.84.181.117 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 99.84.181.117 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I won't even go into the next command which is the upgrade command, because that is also returning 404s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing openjdk-8-jre-headles http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298245/missing-openjdk-8-jre-headles-http-deb-debian-org-debian-jessie-backports-mai)

Comment: Can you provide your sources.list